# Jackson - Custom serializer for propeties inside object

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I'm looking for a way to output all BigIntegers as string using Jackson. These BigIntegers are used in many classes all over my app, so adding @JsonSerialize to all fields is not an option.

I have created a custom Jackson serializer, but this only works on the base class, being serialized, not the properties inside the class. So, this does not work:

```
public class BigIntegerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigInteger> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigInteger value, JsonGenerator jgen,
                      SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeString(value + "");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have a Jackson serialized on all properties of a certain type, without adding @JsonSerialize to all?

The object to be serialized can be any POJO containing BigIntegers.

PS: The idea to convert BigIntegers to String is so that JavaScript will not convert these numbers to scientific notation. All my primary keys use BigInteger, so when JavaScript converts them to scientific notation, I can not longer use them.

Comment: Maybe try a [`Module`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.html)? Note, this is for 2.7; see [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki) for the javadoc of older versions

Comment: I am already using a module, but no use :( is it normal that nested properties are not using serializers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Jackson How-To: Custom Serializers](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers). For example

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
testModule.addSerializer(new BigIntegerSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(testModule);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did, but it doesnt handle BigInteger properties inside the class I want to serialize. Or, is something else (Spring boot) breaking this?

Comment: Try using the addSerializer method that takes a type:  `testModule.addSerializer(BigInteger.class, new BigIntegerSerializer());`. It would also be helpful to update your question with the source code you're using to serialize your object so we can see if there are any mistakes.

Comment: I just found out there was an exception elsewhere in the program that was hidden to me. Looks like all your code was perfect. Thanks for your example.